# Proof verification about a property of the topological space $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, real-numbers

Suppose $A_1,\dots,A_k$ are **connected** open subsets of $[0,1]$ such that $[0,1]=\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i$.
By characterization of connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ I know that each $A_i$ is an interval.

I want to show:

> There exist $0=a_0<a_1<\dots<a_k=1$ real numbers such that $[a_{i-1},a_i]\subseteq A_i$ for each $i\leq k$ (possibly permuting the $A_i$'s)

**My argument**

We can suppose $A_1=[0,c_1)$ with $c_1\in A_2=(b_2,c_2)$. Thus we have $b_2<c_1<c_2$.

Take $a_1$ such that $b_2<a_1<c_1$, thus we have $[0,a_1]\subseteq A_1$, and $a_1\in A_2$.

Suppose $c_2\in A_3=(b_3,c_3)$, thus we have $b_3<c_2<c_3$.

Take $a_2$ such that $b_3<a_2<c_2$. Thus we have $[a_1,a_2]\subseteq A_2$, and $a_2\in A_3$.

Continue in this way until we have $[a_{k-2},a_{k-1}]\subseteq A_{k-1}$ and $a_{k-1}\in A_k$.

Being $1\in A_k$ we have also $[a_{k-1},1]\subseteq A_k$.

> Is my prof correct? (I know I could have used Lebesgue Number Lemma whch is more powerful but since this case is quite special (since the $A_i$'s are all connected) I wanted to try to prove it in a more elementary way).

**EDIT** Assume also $A_i\not\subseteq\bigcup_{j\ne i} A_j$ for each $i$.

**My argument, n°2**

We can suppose $A_1=[0,c_1)$. Since the $A_i$'s cover $[0,1]$ and $c_1\notin A_1$, then it must exists one of the $A_i$ containing $c_1$, (with $i>1$). Let's call it $A_2=(b_2,c_2)$.

I want to show this $A_2$ is **unique**. Suppose we have two candidates: $A_2=(b_2,c_2)$ and $B=(\alpha,\beta)$ where $B$ is one of the other $A_i$'s. This means we have $c_1\in A_2  \cap B$, so $b_2<c_1$ and $\alpha<c_1$. Suppose for example $\alpha< b_2$. So we have $\beta<c_2$ (otherwise we would have $A_2\subseteq B$) and so $B\subseteq A_1\cup A_2$ whis is a contradiction.

Thus we have a **unique** $A_2=(b_2,c_2)$ with $b_2<c_1<c_2$.

Take $a_1$ such that $b_2<a_1<c_1$, thus we have $[0,a_1]\subseteq A_1$, and $a_1\in A_2$.

Arguing as done with $A_2$, we have that it exists a unique $A_3$ such that $c_2\in A_3=(b_3,c_3)$, thus we have $b_3<c_2<c_3$.

Take $a_2$ such that $b_3<a_2<c_2$. Thus we have $[a_1,a_2]\subseteq A_2$, and $a_2\in A_3$.

Continue in this way until we have $[a_{k-2},a_{k-1}]\subseteq A_{k-1}$ and $a_{k-1}\in A_k$.

Being $1\in A_k$ we have also $[a_{k-1},1]\subseteq A_k$.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the case $A_1=[0,0.7), A_2=(0.2, 0.3)$ and $A_3=(0.6, 1]$. I might be missing something, but that looks impossible to me. There is no room for permuting the $A_i$ since the end points must be covered by $A_1$ and $A_3$, and $A_2\cap A_3=\varnothing$ means there is no possible $a_2$.

Comment: your problem looks like, you are taking a refinement of some partition of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Arthur I think you should write that down as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @5xum Usually I would think so too, but often it's either some detail that I've missed, or that the OP has forgotten to include. It is honestly a request for clarification, not an attempt to answer.

Comment: @Arthur, thank-you! :) With the added hypothesis, it the proof correct?

Comment: @5xum And there you have it.

Comment: @Minato Where have you used the fact you just added? Also, the comments by 5xum in his deleted answer come back into play.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I used it to exlude the counterexemple of Arthur

Comment: @Minato Ah, but then that does not exclude any other possible counterexamples that Arthur may not have mentioned, right? I cannot come up with any, but since your proof does not use the fact you have added, it definitely is wrong, for the same reasons that 5xum elaborated in his (now deleted) answer. I can explain this in an answer.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг The fact the the proof does not explicitly name the hypothesis does not mean that it does not (explicitly) **use** it, right? :)

Comment: @Minato Ok, let me put it this way. Your proof is not perfect, I will point out the issues. I do not see where you have used the fact (nothing to do with the proof being wrong) that you have added. If you want, have another go at the problem assuming it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг With the added hypothesis, maybe, now the proof works as it is stated. Maybe certain steps are now correct (even though for completeness I should carefully prove them)

Comment: @Minato Yes, please for the sake of completeness do it, because small details can often be the undoing of a good proof.

Comment: @Arthur https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165714/proof-verification-about-a-property-of-the-topological-space-0-1-part-2 Just for curiosity give a look here :)

Comment: @5xum Just for curiosity give a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165714/proof-verification-about-a-property-of-the-topological-space-0-1-part-2 :) It's a simple statement but yesterday I have learned a lot thank to the hints of you guys :)